# Lubuntu - power button doesn't turn off computer,

Tags: lubuntu, shutdown

I am using Lubuntu 13.04 and would like to have the power button cause the computer to shut down. Currently it only brings up the power preferences menu (logout, reboot, hibernate, etc...).

In Lubuntu, there is xfce4-power-manager v1.2 and I've tried to fix it here by setting the 
**general->when power button is pressed->shut down**
option, but this doesn't change anything.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.  Edit `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh`, and the make sure that the lines below are the last lines in it.

```
# If all else failed, just initiate a plain shutdown.
/sbin/shutdown -h now "Power button pressed"
```

also look in `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`, and make sure it matches below, specially the last part.

```
# /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
# This is called when the user presses the power button and calls
# /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh for further processing.

# Optionally you can specify the placeholder %e. It will pass
# through the whole kernel event message to the program you've
# specified.

# We need to react on "button power.*" and "button/power.*" because
# of kernel changes.

event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

If you make any changes, make sure you run, before you try to see if it works.  You may need to reboot.

```
sudo service acpid restart
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is no acpid service (and the directory /etc/acpi doesn't exist)

Comment: @cloying You can install acpid with `sudo apt-get install acpid`

Comment: Apologies for the delay but just wanted to say this worked for me after installing acpid. Have marked the question as answered.

Answer (score -1):

This is all I needed.

```
xev | grep "keycode"
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Boot_Install_Login#I_want_to_bind_the_power-button_to_change_computer_state.2C_how_do_I_do_it.3F

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How exactly does this make the power button turn off the computer? Please list all the steps you have followed to make the power button directly turn off the computer.